# .NET Core 3.1 - Designer fails on loading - EntityFramework Core

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, entity-framework-core

I have a .Net Core 3.1 project (winforms). For each form I have a baseForm which all forms depend on.

On my base class I have this property

```
        [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]
        public DataContext con { get; set; }
```

Where the DataContext uses the EF Core 3.19. If I try to open the designer of any descendent form of my Baseform I get the following error:

```
at System.Signature.GetSignature(Void* pCorSig, Int32 cCorSig, RuntimeFieldHandleInternal fieldHandle, IRuntimeMethodInfo methodHandle, RuntimeType declaringType)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.FetchNonReturnParameters()
at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.GetParametersNoCopy()
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParametersNoCopy()
at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.GetIndexParameters()
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.ReflectGetProperties(Type type)
at System.ComponentModel.ReflectTypeDescriptionProvider.ReflectedTypeData.GetProperties()
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.TypeDescriptionNode.DefaultTypeDescriptor.System.ComponentModel.ICustomTypeDescriptor.GetProperties()
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetPropertiesImpl(Object component, Attribute[] attributes, Boolean noCustomTypeDesc, Boolean noAttributes)
at System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(Object component)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.GetPropertiesHelper(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object instance, Attribute[] attributes)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Serialization.CodeDomSerializerBase.DeserializePropertiesFromResources(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, Object value, Attribute[] filter)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Serialization.TypeCodeDomSerializer.Deserialize(IDesignerSerializationManager manager, CodeTypeDeclaration declaration)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Sessions.Session.DeserializeToRootComponent(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Sessions.Session.DeserializeRootComponent(CodeTypeDeclaration typeDeclaration, ResourceContentData[] resourceDocDataContent, String basePath)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.Sessions.InitializeRootComponentHandler.HandleRequest(InitializeRootComponentRequest request)
at Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.RequestHandler`2.Microsoft.DotNet.DesignTools.Protocol.Endpoints.IRequestHandler.HandleRequest(Request request)
```

with the message

```
Method 'DisposeAsync' in type 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext' from assembly 'Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=3.1.19.0, ... does not have an implementation.
```

altough in my DataContext I've implemented to following method:

```
        public async ValueTask DisposeAsync()
        {   
            await DisposeAsyncCore();

            Dispose(disposing: false);
            #pragma warning disable CA1816 // Dispose methods should call SuppressFinalize
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
            #pragma warning restore CA1816 // Dispose methods should call SuppressFinalize
        }
```

does anyone have an idea what could cause my problem? My designer should completly skip the DataContext property..

Comment: Why are you using .Net Core 3.1? Move to .Net 5 and update your version of Entity Framework Core.

Comment: Does Winforms work fine with .net 5?

Comment: Much better than Core 3.1 for sure. WinForms Core 3.1 was just a *rite of passage*. EF Core 5.0 was released at the same time .Net 5 was ready. Update that, too. .Net 6 will work with EF Core 6.

Comment: .NET 5 with EF Core 5 indeed fixed the issue!